# Laravel 8 @yeild @section not passing data blank page

Tags: php, laravel

When I use @yiedl my main webiste it's blank, not importing any data from other view.

**code in main file**

```
<body>
    @yield('content')
```

Code in home.blade.php file

```
@extends('Templates.weball')
    @section('content')
    <div class="top" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
        <video autoplay preload="none" disablepictureinpicture="none" muted loop>
            <source src="strony/assets/movies/Untitled3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>....
@endsection
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure that the naming of the folder and file is correct :) Its case sensitive, that's why. Other than that, looks good.

Comment: Can you try `php artisan view:clear` ?

Comment: Now yes and still nothing

Answer (score 0):

You are going the wrong way. Assuming master is your main layout file, index extends master, not the other way around.

in index.blade.php

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')

    <!--  html specific to the index page -->

@endsection
```

In master.blade.php

```
<!--  all your layout codes -->

@yield('content')

<!-- rest of layout -->
```

Comment: So wait if in web.php I have route `Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('Templates/weball');
});` it's not my main file?